# How to clear checkboxes and set one checkbox in JIRA postfunction using Groovy with Adapatvist ScriptRunner

Tags: checkbox, groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I have a Groovy script Post-Function using Adapatvist scriptRunner that creates sub tasks based on what checkboxes are checked on the parent issue during creation.

How do I clear all of those check boxes from the parent issue in a Post-Function and set the parent's checkbox selection to just one (different) check?

The following is an example of a ScriptRunner Post-Function to create a subtask based on what product checkboxes were checked. All of these Post-Functions occur *after* the **Creates the issue originally** step.

**Condition:** http://pastebin.com/k8UbjQhs

**Target Issue Type:** Sub-task

**Additional issue actions:** http://pastebin.com/nSStL6b5

I have 10 unique Products that could be checked onduring the parent issue creation. I know I need the step where I would scrub to come after all of these Sub-task creating steps but *before* Storing updates to an issue or Re-indexing the issue.

I would like to run a script that, before the Re-index of the Original Parent issue being creating, will make sure that it only has one single product value checked. For example we'll call that product *Parent Issue*

Comment: Can you post your code to pastebin and put the link here?

Comment: edited main description to include pastebin examples